# Complex "IF", "OR", "AND" functions

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, logical-operators

Here is what I have done so far: (See screenshot attached)

When something is added under "Laden" it gets a certain status. If this status is either "Warte auf GO" or "Warte auf Daten" AND the Date in the Datefield D2 is more than 6 days ago, I want the color of the cell under "Laden" which has now "Baretta" in it to become yellow.
To do so, I have added the simple function:

```
=OR(AND(L4="warte auf GO"; 6<DAYS360(D4; today())); AND(L4="warte auf DATEN"; 6<DAYS360(D4; today())))
```

And used conditional formatting. So if this returns true, color A2 in yellow.
This worked.

But now to the problem: Secondly if the field turns yellow, I have three more "reminder"-cells:

(1) I have been reminded with a yellow field A2 and put the date I have reacted on the reminder in field N2. If 6 days are over, A2 turns yellow again.
(2) So I have been reminded with a yellow field A2 for the second time and put the date I have reacted on the reminder in field O2. If 6 days are over, A2 turns yellow again.
(3) Again like (2).

So basically I use this sheet as a "reminder"-system with different stages.
I have tried to solve it with the following formula. It does return some "false" and "trues", but not in an order, that I fully understand.
I guess this is a logical problem, but I do not really see it.

Here is the formula I used:

```
=IF(AND(OR(L4="warte auf GO"; L4="warte auf DATEN"); 6<DAYS360(D4; today());(OR(N4=""; AND(6<DAYS360(N4; today()); O4=""); AND(6<DAYS360(O4; today()); P4=""); AND(6<DAYS360(P4; today()))))); true; false)
```

Comment: So what happens with the new formular is, that it gives me exactly the value the formular above returns.
So not really a change ;-)

Comment: No screenshot was attached, even though you said it at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your question very carefully and tried to find the answer. It seems that the following formula does what you need:

```
=if(or(L4="warte auf GO",L4="warte auf DATEN"),if(today()-D4>6,if(today()-N4>6,if(today()-O4>6,if(today()-P4>6,true)))))
```

It's very straightforward:
If `or(L4="warte auf GO",L4="warte auf DATEN")`, you go ahead into the formula.
If `today()-D4>6`, you go ahead.
If `today()-N4>6`, you go ahead.
If `today()-O4>6`, you go ahead.
If `today()-P4>6`, you get `TRUE`, because this is the final step.

If ANY of the steps above is NOT evaluated to `TRUE`, you do not get further - you get OUT of all of those `if's` and the final result is given as `FALSE`.

---

**Additional note.**
I don't recommend you using [`days360()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093042?hl=en) in normal everyday calculations. It is only useful in **financial** calculations. There are cases where that formula would yield incorrect results. For instance, all of the following formulas return the same result of **`30`**:

```
=days360(date(2015,7,31),date(2015,8,30))
=days360(date(2015,7,31),date(2015,8,31))
=days360(date(2015,7,30),date(2015,8,31))
```

This results in **`0`**:

```
=days360(date(2015,7,30),date(2015,7,31))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for late reply, I was on holiday.
So what I did is brake the formular you gave me apart in 4 pieces. With that it did work perfectly. I was not able to put it back together as I somehow got an error. This probably has to do with me missing out on a "(" or something ;-).
Thanks again.

But what do you recommend for not using "days360" ?

Comment: E.g. in the case of `DAYS360(D4; today())` you could use `today()-D4`